# What is the meaning of (/^\s+|\s+$/gm) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across this JavaScript function:

```
function myTrim(x) {
  return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}
```

I know that this function(`mytrim()`) replaces some characters in the string(x), but what does `/^\s+|\s+$/gm` do in the replace method?

Where can I learn more about these things?

Note- This function returns the string with removed spaces at both sides.

Comment: While JavaScript is a language, it is very commonly—but not exclusively—used in the context of the HTML DOM in a web browser. That makes web documentation a great place for learning JavaScript in general. The major web browser vendors have [centralized](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2017/10/18/mozilla-brings-microsoft-google-w3c-samsung-together-create-cross-browser-documentation-mdn/) their general documentation efforts at [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/). The keywords, in this case, are "replace" and "RegExp".

Comment: @aryaman, have you found a suitable solution in any of those # answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is a regular expression search that matches two alternative patterns:

`/^\s+|\s+$/gm`

`/` Regex separator

`|` Alternatives separator

**First Alternative `^\s+`**

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `\s+` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**Second Alternative `\s+$`**

- `\s+` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

**Global pattern flags**

- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
- `m` modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

You can read more details on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/x2KaZP/1).

**Function explanation**

The function call `return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');` searches for any spaces from the beginning of the string and from the end of string.
If found then it is replaced by empty string `''`.
Simply said it does the trim whitespace characters:

- `\n`  carriage return (ASCII 13)
- `\r` line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
- `\t` tab character (ASCII 9)
- `\f` form-feed character (ASCII 12)
- `\v` any vertical whitespace character

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is called a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (often shortened to *RegEx*); there are multiple places you can learn this, but you can try [this one](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

There are also multiple websites to test such regular expressions such as [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Note that regular expressions are not a universal standard; there are variants depending on the programming language and platform (for example, grep, extended grep, Perl, Java, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

It is a regular expression.

That pattern replaces all whitespace characters `\s+` by an empty string depending on that is is at the beginning of string `^\s+` or `|` at the end of the string `\s+$`.

`g` is for global modifier, what doesn't return after first match.

`m` is for multiline.

Answer (score 2):

^\s+|\s+$gm

### 1st Alternative (^\s+)

^   asserts position at start of a line

\s+  matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

+Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

### 2nd Alternative (\s+$)

\s+ matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

+Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

$ asserts position at the end of a line

### Global pattern flags:

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)